# How to add indexes with a for loop from a multidimensional array using C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, variables, indexing, sum

I am trying to get the random sum of i into the four variables scoreTotalOne, scoreTotalTwo, scoreTotalThree, and scoreTotalFour. I am not getting the correct answer in the output? Any help will be appreciated.

```
        //array for par 
        int[] parArray = { 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4};
        
        //multi-rectangular array 18 holes, 4 golfers
        int[,] arr = new int[18, 4];

        //generate random scores for holes/golfers
        Random randomScores = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("Hole Par Golfer 1 Golfer 2 Golfer 3 Golfer 4");

        int scoreTotalOne = 0;
        int scoreTotalTwo = 0;
        int scoreTotalThree = 0;
        int scoreTotalFour = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((i + 1) + "\t");
            Console.Write(parArray[i] + "\t");

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {

                arr [i, j] = randomScores.Next(parArray [i] - 2, parArray [i] + 3);
                Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");
                scoreTotalOne += arr[i, j];
                scoreTotalTwo += arr[i, j];
                scoreTotalThree += arr[i, j];
                scoreTotalFour += arr[i, j];

            }

            Console.WriteLine();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Front"  + " " + scoreTotalOne + " " + scoreTotalTwo + " " + scoreTotalThree + " " + scoreTotalFour);
```

Comment: What _is_ the correct answer, and what are you getting?

Comment: @AstridE. I am continually getting 144. It is supposed a sum of the generated random numbers from the loop

Comment: What values are filled into your matrix after random generation?

Comment: @Jasen If you are referring to the random generation, the numbers are changing each time I run the program

Comment: I think you're trying to do this `scoreTotalOne += arr[i,j];`.

Comment: @iSR5 Yes that is closer however I am trying to make it so the 4 sets of random numbers from the index j are not added together

Comment: "the sum of the index i" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @m24 is this is what are you looking for ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/eGjIDV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more array, instead of four separate variables. This will make it easy to pick only (the right) one of the totals to update in the inner loop. Otherwise, all four scores will always get the score of the final golfer, since the inner loop currently sets all four variables. It will look like this:

```
int[] holePars = { 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4};
int[,] holeScores = new int[18, 4];// 18 holes, 4 golfers
int[] totals = {0, 0, 0, 0};

var randomScores = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("Hole Par Golfer 1 Golfer 2 Golfer 3 Golfer 4");

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"  {i + 1}{holePars[i],4}     ");

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        holeScores[i,j] = randomScores.Next(holePars[i] - 2, holePars[i] + 3);
        Console.Write($"{holeScores[i,j],-9}");
        totals[j] += holeScores[i,j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Front {totals[0]} {totals[1]} {totals[2]} {totals[3]}");
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/6XSLES

---

I like what you've done with the deviation from par for getting the random scores. If you really want to make this look more like a real golf game, you could also create *weights* for the scores, so golfers are more likely to end up closer to par. That might look like this:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/qoUOWf

The code at the above link makes you more than 4 times as likely to hit a par over a double eagle, where the original was purely random.

Additionally, it would be fun to also weight golfer skills once at the beginning, so you're less likely to have the same golfer get both triple bogeys and eagles.

Comment: Hey thanks this helped a lot and I was able to fix what I needed with you explanation!